# Ubuntu Software Centre - error

Tags: 11.10, software-center

When I am trying to install any application from Ubuntu Software Centre , It is throwing below messages..

> Failed to download package files. Check your Internet connection

But when I try from terminal it is working fine ..!

I have no issue with my internet, it is working fine. I tried below things,

```
apt-get remove software-centre
apt-get install software-centre
apt-get install updates
apt-get install upgrades
```

But , No USE

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution i had the same problem and this post helped me

### http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-the-ubuntu-gpg-error-badsig.html

but before that i suggest you to change your source.list file using this site (optional but worked for me)

### http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

select your os version and then check all entries under "Ubuntu branches" and "Ubuntu updates" and select Ubuntu partner for those you want to receive updates.
and add extra repositories if you want to.

### How to change source.list?

if you have generated new source.list from repogen.simplylinux.ch then open terminal and type

> gksu nautilus

go to /etc/apt/sources.list
and backup source.list(rename it)
copy your downloaded source.list file and run update once again

Hope that helped

Comment: glad that helped :)